# How to bind controller to directive?

Tags: angularjs

I used directive to format number to currency, it's used to work fine until i separated the template from the directive. now its not working.

DIRECTIVE

```
<number-input ng-model="vm.currencyVal" ng-change="vm.mychangeShovi()"
              ng-class="vm.currencyValMsg">
</number-input>
```

SCRIPT

```
angular.module('SvUtilities')
.directive('numberInput', function ($filter) {    
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                return setDisplayNumber(modelValue, true);
            });
            elem.bind('keyup focus', function () {
                setDisplayNumber(elem.val());
            });

            function setDisplayNumber(val, formatter) {
                var valStr, displayValue;
                if (typeof val === 'undefined') {
                    return null;
                }
                valStr = val.toString();
                displayValue = valStr.replace(/,/g, '').replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, '');

                displayValue = parseFloat(displayValue);

                displayValue = (!isNaN(displayValue)) ? displayValue.toString() : '';



                // handle leading character -/0

                if (valStr.length === 1 && valStr[0] === '-') {

                    displayValue = valStr[0];

                } else if (valStr.length === 1 && valStr[0] === '0') {

                    displayValue = '';

                } else {

                    displayValue = $filter('number')(displayValue);

                }





                if (attrs.positive && displayValue[0] === '-') {

                    displayValue = displayValue.substring(1);

                }



                if (typeof formatter !== 'undefined') {

                    return (displayValue === '') ? 0 : displayValue;

                } else {

                    elem.val((displayValue === '0') ? '' : displayValue);

                }

            }



            function setModelNumber(val) {

                var modelNum = val.toString().replace(/,/g, '').replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, '');

                modelNum = parseFloat(modelNum);

                modelNum = (!isNaN(modelNum)) ? modelNum : 0;

                if (modelNum.toString().indexOf('.') !== -1) {

                    modelNum = Math.round((modelNum + 0.00001) * 100) / 100;

                }

                if (attrs.positive) {

                    modelNum = Math.abs(modelNum);

                }

                return modelNum;

            }

        },

        restrict: "E",

        replace: true,

        templateUrl: "../svAngularLib/modules/utilities/directives/currencyDir.html",

        scope: {

            cssColor: '=',

            onChange: '&',

        },

        controllerAs: 'vm',

        bindToController: true

    };

});
```

TEMPLATE

```
<div>
    <input maxlength="16" type='text' number-input ng-model="vm.currencyVal"
           value="vm.currencyVal" ng-change="" ng-class="" />    
    <span class="input-group-addon">₪</span>
</div>
```

When typing numbers its should add commas separators, also i want to add some function (ng-change) to it or proprieties (CSS class)

Comment: You need to add a `controller: [function(){}],` to your directive object.  Shouldn't have anything to do with separating the template file though, just to do with the `controllerAs` and `bindToController` items.

Comment: it did not work. i added pluker to show plnkr.co/edit/9F0I7ZoyERUsqgqOqSpF?p=preview

Comment: The plunker doesn't work because of some other issues (and for some reason mine isn't saving), not our suggestions.  You're not initializing the module correctly, nor are you applying it to the index.html file (ng-controller).  The other issue is in the directive `elem` is not the input, you need to do an `angular.element` to lookup the input inside the `number-input` and apply it appropriately.  I would suggest simplifying this to an Attribute directive with no template and only working off ngModel for it's purpose.

Comment: I am new to plunker so i don't know how to let you edit...

Comment: That's fine, it's not a huge deal.  I'm just letting you know that the plunkr doesn't work, not because of the changes we're asking you to make, but because of some other issues related to Angular itself.  Regardless, adding the controller should resolve your issue in your own project.  What error are you getting now?  Or no errors and its just not working?

Answer (score 0):

It's missing a property `controller` on your directive:

```
app.controller('SomeController', function () {
  ...
});

app.directive('directiveName', function () {
  return {
    ...
    controller: 'SomeController',
    ...
  };
});
```

Comment: it did not work. i added pluker to show https://plnkr.co/edit/9F0I7ZoyERUsqgqOqSpF?p=preview